# How can i send local notification in background(while app terminate)?

Tags: swift, background, uilocalnotification

i want to send local notf. For this, i will listen my web service every 5 seconds. If there is a new message i will send this user local notification. I don't have a developer account so i can not use remote notificaitons. I want to send local notf like AlarmManager in Android, so how can i do this?

Comment: If you app is terminated it can't run in background, take a look at [background execution in ios](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/about_the_background_execution_sequence)

Comment: if i want to make an alarm app? Or alarm apps that in app store, how can they run?

Comment: Oh, you can [scheduling a local notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app), this way your app doesn't need to run in background

Comment: You can schedule a notification like other told you but if by any means it is not enough you can also play on loop a muted audio and add the correct background state for the application... any way it will NOT be accepted by apple on a review and is not a good practice neither